# How to interact with a locally running datastore service in appengine-magic?

Tags: google-app-engine, clojure, appengine-magic

I'm using appengine-magic to set up a web application, more or less as described at http://www.digitalbricklayers.com/2012/03/geotasklist-in-jquery-mobile-and.html. The example works on my local machine, locations and tasks are added to a local datastore etc.

My question is if it is possible to interact with the datastore from within a REPL, e.g. call (ds/save! ...) etc. during interactive development? I ask because when I try I get:

NullPointerException No API environment is registered for this thread.
   com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper.getCurrentAppId 
   (DatastoreApiHelper.java:108)

I'm getting this error no matter if I use an eclipse+counterclockwise based setup or an emacs+slime based setup.

Thanks,
Joachim

Answer (score 0):

There's a bunch of ways to do this.

The easiest way is to go to the admin console (http://localhost:/_ah/admin) and click on the "Interactive Console".

I use django-nonrel, which comes with a command to launch an interactive shell (manage.py shell).  If you're not using django-nonrel though, getting it set up though, is somewhat involved.  I suspect most of what's necessary is found in the setup_env() function in django-nonrel: https://github.com/django-nonrel/djangoappengine/blob/develop/djangoappengine/boot.py
Getting it all to work is a pain, good luck.

The solution I use 99% of the time is to use pdb and force the interpreter to break at a certain point in my app where I need to do some debugging.  See this for instructions: http://eatdev.tumblr.com/post/12076034867/using-pdb-on-app-engine

Answer (score 0):

appengine-magic lets you use App Engine services (like the datastore) as long as the application is running; see https://github.com/gcv/appengine-magic#app-engine-services — as long as you `ae/start` your application, it should work.